# Additional space when creating navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar using CSS. I get an additional space on the left when I load the HTML. Could you please help me in identifying what could be wrong.

```css
/* Navigation Bar Properties */

.navigation {
  background-color: #404040;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.navigationText {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigationText li {
  display: inline;
}

.navigationText li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.navigationText li a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigationText">
    <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would ideally like **Home** button to be placed at left without any space.
Any inputs

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove space around the `ul`'s content setting the `padding` property value:

```
.navigationText {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I was under the impression that padding would be 0 by default.

Comment: @Vaishak , welcome! A browser has embedded CSS, so it is better to define such rules directly.  Use browser development tools to see actual CSS values for an element.